# How to implement specific counts of thread in Gatling

Tags: multithreading, scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

Is there any possibility to setup Gatling scenario to run in specific counts of thread? For instance, I want to execute 1M requests during 1hour in 2500 threads.

And also, does each scenario (in setUp(scn.inject())) will be running in different thread? What does "thread" means in Gatling-definition - is it the same as in Java?

I found a [topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/gvBqzUpswJw), but it's not exactly what I need (in case of topic-started he needed only 3 threads, but for me - counts much bigger).

I have

```
val scn = scenario("Test")
    .exec(mine)
}

setUp(
    scn.inject(
        rampUsers(1000000) over (3600)
     )
).assertions(global.successfulRequests.percent.greaterThan(95))
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/gvBqzUpswJw) you've cited, number of threads that Gatling will use to fire the requests against your target system under test is not number of concurrent users. It is implementation detail.

Gatling uses [Akka](http://akka.io/) under the hood and issues the requests asynchronously. This asynchronous nature means that Gatling is using a few threads to fire all the requests. If you want to know more see [gatling-akka-defaults.conf](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html#Default_dispatcher). It uses Akka [Default Dispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html#Default_dispatcher) which uses fork-join pool with aprox. number of CPU cores * 2 threads (not certain at 100%, see doc).

As was already mentioned in cited topic, question is **What do you mean by "user"?**.

As I understood it, your goal is to have a load 2500 concurrent users against your system. It does not matter if the Gatling will uses 2 or 1000 threads to achieve this.

So if you want 2500 concurrent users (per second) it is easy to write just:

```
setUp(
  scn.inject( constantUsersPerSec(2500) during(3600) )
)...
```

If you on other hand want a 2500 distinct populations (which is IMO not desired) you can achieve this too, by:

```
// `scn` have to be function, while scenarios should havce distinct name
def scn(name: String) = scenario(name)
  .exec(
    http("root").get("/")
  )

setUp(
  (for {
    i <- 0 until 2500 // desired 2500
   } yield {
    scn(s"Test $i").inject(
      rampUsers(1) over (3600)
    )
  }).toList // setUp can accept List[PopulationBuilder]
)
```

Populations should be used to inject different scenarios or different type of users at the same time with its own rate and duration. For example see [Advanced Tutorial, Step 2](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/advanced_tutorial.html#step-02-configure-virtual-users). They are not intended to simulate concurrent users. You can see that directly from the code that syntactically the solution is possible but cumbersome.